# .bashrc not executed when opening new terminal

Tags: login, bashrc

The code in `.bashrc` does not execute when I open a new terminal window in Ubuntu 12.04.
I noticed this when creating a `.bash_aliases` file.  The aliases did not show up when I opened a new terminal.  However when I type `source .bashrc` the aliases did show up.

`.bashrc` should be run every time I open a new terminal window, right?

How do I make this happen?

Comment: Try .profile instead.

Comment: @jippie No, `.profile` is read at login time, not when you open a new terminal, unless there's a misconfiguration somewhere. Selah: did you change anything from the default configuration? Please run `ps -o command $$ $PPID` in a terminal and copy-paste the output.

Comment: Just to make positive sure, you are putting `.bashrc` in your home folder, right?

Comment: Might want to check `echo $SHELL`.  This happened to me and the shell was /bin/sh instead of bash.  Fix it in /etc/passwd and its running .bashrc.

Comment: this happened to me because I accidentally ran `$ rm -r ~`

Comment: In my case deleting unused but existing `$HOME/.bash_profile` worked.

Comment: @K.Stopa The reason deleting `~/.bash_profile` worked is because Bash prefers to use that instead of `~/.profile` if it is found.

Answer (score 248, accepted):

It isn't necessarily run; at the top of the standard .bashrc is this comment:

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples
```

I believe there is an option to run bash terminal as a login shell or not.  With Ubuntu, gnome-terminal does not normally run as a login shell, so .bashrc should be run directly.

For login shells (like the virtual terminals), normally the file `~/.profile` is run, unless you have either `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login`, but they are not there by default.  By default, Ubuntu uses only .profile.

The standard `~/.profile` has this in it:

```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

This runs .bashrc if it is available - assuming $BASH_VERSION is present in your environment.  You can check for this by entering the command `echo $BASH_VERSION`, and it should display some information on version number - it should not be blank.

Comment: After understanding these instructions, I went in my terminal application I went to edit -> profile preferences -> Title and Command -> Run command as a login shell.  I unchecked this.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you clarify when .profile (hence .bashrc) is loaded/read? It seems this is done when the users logs in to their desktop session. The answer suggests this occurs when you start a new terminal/shell session "For login shells (like the virtual terminals), normally the file ~/.profile is run... "

Comment: It is _normally_ run when you start a new login shell (not really desktop session, because you can run a new login shell from the desktop session).  As I said, it is run by default, but not if you have created `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login`.  You can test by checking or unchecking the checkbox in `Edit -> Profile Preferences -> Title and Command -> "Run command as a login shell`, and exit then rerun the terminal.  You could echo something from .profile to test.

Comment: @Selah Your comment helped me more then the actual answer ;) thanks a lot for making the comment!

Comment: So if you have created `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login` on your system and want to keep them, but still want `~/.profile` and from there `~/.bashrc` executed, you can source it from your own `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login` with a line containing `source "$HOME/.profile"`. Gives you back the colored output of ls also in login shells!

Comment: Thank you for this post... just an FYI, this worked on RHEL also...

Comment: @jasonflaherty - glad it helped after such a long time. I'm not really surprised it also works with other distros - it's fairly basic.

Comment: just realized my terminal was loading zsh instead of bash! changed .zshrc to source aliases from .bash_aliases

Comment: Thank you, it seems cPanel overwrites default .bash_profile with it's own greeting message, causing this issue

Answer (score 76):

In my case, simply the `.bashrc` loader lines were missing in `.bash_profile`

```
# include .bashrc if it exists
if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
fi
```

I added it manually and it worked with my fresh login

Comment: `.bash_profile`? Ubuntu uses a `.profile` by default, not `.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 17):

`.bash_profile` holds configuration for the bash shell. When you open a terminal, it first reads and executes commands from `~/.bash_profile`. So you can add the following in `.bash_profile` to setup the shell according to bashrc.

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Unless your terminal is running a login shell (which it doesn't by default in Ubuntu), `~/.bash_profile` won't be read (and it doesn't exist by default in Ubuntu)

Answer (score 10):

According to the comment in `.profile`

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
```

So there you go; if `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login` exists, those will get run instead of `~/.profile`.

If you want to run `~/.bashrc` just add the line `source ~/.bashrc` in `bash_profile`.

Comment: I have experienced the exact same issue. My `.bashrc` was being sourced until I created a `.bash_profile` file. So I prepended `source ~/.bashrc ` line to my `.bash_profile` file.

Answer (score 7):

If `$BASH_VERSION` is not set, try using the `chsh` command to set your shell to `/bin/bash`.

I had a similar issue with 12.04 LTS, and it turned out the new user account had the default shell set to `/bin/sh`, which was the cause of the problem.

Comment: This was the reason!

Comment: 9 years later, and still ubuntu creates new users with a broken shell... :-/

Answer (score 4):

It was pretty simple for me. I installed mssqltools and somehow it created a file `bash_profile` in $HOME directory. As `bash_profile` runs before `bashrc` is picked up, if you don't have a `source` command in `bash_profile`, `bashrc` won't run.

There are two ways to tackle this, either delete `bash_profile` or if you use `bash_profile`, just add the following line anywhere in the file

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: In my case, meteor installed a .bash_profile.  adding `source ~/.bashrc` worked!

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 20.x in order for the `.bashrc` to be read when a terminal is opened, you should copy the template `.profile` into the user directory (`.bashrc` is loaded from `.profile`):

```
sudo cp /etc/skel/.profile ~/.profile && sudo chown $(whoami):$(whoami) ~/.profile
```