# How to create a keyboard shortcut for a terminal command

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

I often work with git and loved iTerm2 for the ability to set keyboard shortcuts for commands. For example, I set <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to `git status`.

Is this possible with gnome-terminal or can you recommend another option to achieve this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use `bind -x` to bind a command to a shortcut in Bash. For example, to bind `git status` command to <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> shortcut you can use:

```
 bind -x '"\C-p":git status'
```

Put it into `~/.bashrc` file to remember it. From man page:

> -x keyseq:shell-command
>
> Cause shell-command to be executed whenever keyseq is entered. When shell-command is executed, the shell sets the
>   READLINE_LINE variable to the contents of the Readline line buffer and
>   the READLINE_POINT variable to the current location of the insertion
>   point. If the executed command changes the value of READLINE_LINE or
>   READLINE_POINT, those new values will be reflected in the editing
>   state.

Comment: Awesome. I'm using zsh but that has an equivalent called [bindkey](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-bindkey). So to achieve what I want I did this: 

`bindkey -s '^[^M' 'git status\n'` which binds to ALT+ENTER.

Comment: `bind -x '"\C-k":firefox'` I use this but doesn't works

Comment: This works in shell, but I want all time.

Comment: Put it at the end of `~/.bashrc` file. If it still doesn't work, check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161249/bashrc-not-executed-when-opening-new-terminal)

Comment: More info on using `bind` can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4201274/712334

Comment: As mentioned [here](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/bash/bind.htm), you can press `CTRL + v` at a bash prompt, then press the key combo. This action is called quoted-insert.

Answer (score 4):

### 1. Automatically open a new terminal window, showing the output of your command

Since you need to keep the terminal open after the command ran, putting:

```
gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c "git status; read line"'
```

under a shortcut key combination, will do the job. It will open a *new* `gnome-terminal` window and run the command inside it.

#### Add it to a shortcut

Choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command:

```
gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c "git status; read line"'
```

to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

#### Note

Although your suggested shortcut works, you might pick another key combination then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, since it *at least* clashes with the `LibreOffice` shortcut to jump to a new page.

#### Explanation

To have a new `gnome-terminal` window opened from command line, and run a command in it, you can use:

```
gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c <command>'
```

However, although the command will run successfully, the terminal window will close immediately before you can read the output.

The section:

```
read line
```

is then to keep the terminal open (until you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>) after the command runs.

#### Other commands

This way, you can run any (complex) command in the terminal, without having it closed immediately:

```
$ gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c "wmctrl -d; read line"'
```

will output (if `wmctrl` is installed):

[image]

After pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> the terminal will close.

### 2. Running a command in the currently active gnome-terminal window

Of course you *could* place a simple one-liner under a shortcut key (assuming you have `xdotool` installed):

```
xdotool type "<command>"
```

This would however type the command *blindly*, in *any* application, and *typing* the command is not the cleanest option.

The small script below therefore:

- looks if the active window is a `gnome-terminal` window (by its pid)
- if so, it *pastes* the command in the active `gnome-terminal` window, presses <kbd>Return</kbd>. 
  If not, the script does *nothing*, So it won't paste into other applications.

Since the script takes the targeted command as an argument, you can put multiple commands under multiple shortcuts.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import sys
import time

app = "gnome-terminal"
s = (" ").join(sys.argv[1:])

def get(cmd):
    return subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8").strip()

def front(app):
    try:
        # see if gnome-terminal is running at all (raising error if not)
        app = get(["pgrep", app]) 
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        app = False
    if app:
        # if so, see if the active window belongs to gnome-terminal comparing pids)
        active = get(["xdotool", "getwindowpid", get(["xdotool", "getactivewindow"])])
        return True if app == active else False

if front(app):
    # copy command to clipboard
    cm1 = ["/bin/bash", "-c", 'printf "'+s+'" | xclip -selection clipboard']
    # paste in terminal window
    cm2 = ["xdotool", "key", "Control_L+Shift_L+v"]
    # press return
    cm3 = ["xdotool", "key", "Return"]
    for cm in [cm1, cm2, cm3]:
        subprocess.call(cm)
```

#### How to use

1. The script needs `xdotool`

   sudo apt-get install xdotool
2. Create a dirctory `~/bin` if it doesn't exist yet, either log out out/in or run `source ~/.profile`
3. Copy the script above into an empty file, save it as `gterm_keys` (no extension) in `~/bin`, an ***make it executable***

Now You can run *any* command, from a shortcut key, in the frontmost `gnome-terminal` window by adding the command:

```
gterm_keys <command>
```

to a shortcut key, as described in **`[1]`**

Comment: Hi Jacob, thanks for your answer. I think, though, the bind (and bindkey) solutions are better as they're shell-builtins. That way I won't accidentally write "git status" in Libreoffice. ;)

Comment: @mniess I agree the answer is a good one, but for the record, if you read my answer carefully, *printing in LibreOffice, that cannot happen*. but did you just *downvote??* That's hilarious.

Comment: I know, the script checks for the running app. I didn't downvote. I wrote the comment to thank you for taking the time to write such a detailed answer.

Comment: @mniess Ah, sorry for jumping to conclusions! The two happened perfectly synchronized. I am glad it wasn't you. "Just" a downvote I don't mind.

Answer (score 3):

In case zsh is used instead of bash, the following line in `~/.zshrc` binds `git status` to <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

```
bindkey -s '^[^M' 'git status\n'
```

To get <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> in Bash, I use this line:

```
bind -x '"\e\C-m":git status'
```

Comment: How would one go about identifying the bindings for other keys?

Comment: @JoshHabdas look here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76566/where-do-i-find-a-list-of-terminal-key-codes-to-remap-shortcuts-in-bash