# Exiting shell with new command line

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh, java

I'm running a third party Java program on a VM instance on Google Compute Engine with Ubuntu 18.04.

I have an automated workflow that runs the Java program via SSH and executes my desired function. That all works perfectly fine but the problem I'm having is that when exiting the Java program with an `exit` or `quit` command, no new command line is opened which means the subsequent `exit` command is not implemented. It simply hangs indefinitely. It looks like the following:

```
shell:>quit
```

(new empty line here but should be `user@project:~$`)

The only way to open a new command line is to enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> i.e. `^C`. Then entering `exit` closes the shell. But since this is intended to be an automated process that continues to the next stage in my workflow, it's no use if it can only be terminated with manual intervention. I've tried `kill <pid>` in the new empty line but that isn't effective. Any suggestions as to how I can close the shell with a command without having to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> would be most welcome.

I'm not an experienced programmer so I apologise for any incorrect terminology or lack of clarity.

Comment: You can use bind keyword for this. Please see URL  for reference https://askubuntu.com/questions/748963/how-to-create-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-a-terminal-command

Comment: what about system call commands? I'm not an expert in Java, but you could probably generate something like `system("exit")`

Comment: Thanks @PrinceKumarBarnwal I'll give this a try. Was starting to think along these lines.

Comment: Thanks @damadam - will look into this.

Comment: After further digging, it seems to be an issue with Spring boot exit/quit command and Threads remaining open https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-shell/issues/284

Comment: Great It seems your problem is solved @Jimbroni